# XML namespaces conflicts

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I was wondering why do we have to define our namespaces with an URI that is unique for our organization (just like packages in Java). That would obviously make sense and let us avoid name conflicts. However, [this page](http://www.sitepoint.com/xml-namespaces-explained/) says:

> It is also possible (though not recommended) for the same prefix refer
>   to different namespaces, depending on their context

So basically if I have my own XML document with my own namespace prefix `myNamespace` defined as `http://hisdomain.com/test`, somebody could redefine the 'myNamespace' prefix to point to his own namespace `http://hisdomain.com/test`, **even by mistake** (I think there is no alert if I define a namespace prefix that has been already defined in the document).

Even with URIs, other people need to make sure they don't use my prefix!

Then using URIs and having to provide definitions to namespaces becomes useless, the namespace system would work equally well if we simply used the prefixes only without having to provide definitions using `xlns` attribute.

---

If I understand correctly, this is not allowed:

```
<root xmlns:abc="mydomain.com/test" xmlns:abc="yourdomain.com/test">
...
</root>
```

but this one is okay - you could redefine the `abc` prefix with your domain.

```
<root xmlns:abc="mydomain.com/test">
    <body xmlns:abc="yourdomain.com/test">
    ...//to use my namespace here, I'd need to redefine it again to mydomain.com/test

    </body>
</root>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Even with URIs, other people need to make sure they don't use my
>   prefix!

Correct, within an XML document, namespace prefix declarations should not conflict.

The key, however, is that the namespace prefix itself is insignificant.  It is syntactic sugar for the full namespace name.  Conformant XML processors will not care what you or other parties use for namespace prefixes.  Namespace prefixes are just shorthand conveniences; namespace names are what matter.

> Then using URIs and having to provide definitions to namespaces
>   becomes useless, the namespace system would work equally well if we
>   simply used the prefixes only without having to provide definitions
>   using xlns attribute.

Not true.

The namespace system would not work equally well if component names were burdened with having to be long enough to support the uniqueness requirements of namespace names.  We wouldn't like the extra verbosity.

---

**Update for new addition to question:**

Correct, this is not allowed (similar to how two attributes could not have the same name for a given element):

```
<root xmlns:abc="mydomain.com/test" xmlns:abc="yourdomain.com/test">
```

But this is allowed (but better avoided):

```
<root xmlns:abc="mydomain.com/test">
    <body xmlns:abc="yourdomain.com/test">
    ...//to use my namespace here, I'd need to redefine it again to mydomain.com/test

    </body>
</root>
```

Comment: Okay, suppose I use `abc` prefix for `mydomain.com/test` namespace in a document. Now you take my document and add your stuff, using your own namespace `yourdomain.com/test`. If you used `abc` prefix as well, it could overwrite my namespace. To make sure your namespace has absolutely no influence on the namespace I've introduced in the document, you need to use a different prefix. Correct? That was my point. Yes, I'm aware that XML parsers just look at the prefix and jump directly to its definition. But the problem of conflicts doesn't completely go away even with URIs. Or I don't get it.

Comment: Correct, within an XML document, namespace prefix declarations cannot conflict.  Answer updated.

Comment: Hmm, but what about the quote in my question? Is it not true anymore? My guess is that you can't define two namespaces with the same name in one XML element (node), but you can overwrite the namespace definition in a child node. It still causes problems I've given above (I'd have to re-introduce the original namespace definition in all child nodes from that point If I wanted to use my namespace instead of the one you've introduced).

Comment: Your statement that "using URIs and having to provide definitions to namespaces becomes useless, the namespace system would work equally well if we simply used the prefixes only without having to provide definitions using xlns attribute" remains untrue as I've already explained in the answer.

Comment: Fine, but I didn't even refer to that. I'm asking if _It is also possible (though not recommended) for the same prefix refer to different namespaces, depending on their context_ (quote from the article) is true or not, because you've changed your mind.

Comment: Yes, your question update reflects a correct understanding.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The point is every namespace has its own scope. A descendant namespace declaration can override the same prefix that is defined in an ancestor.

For example, the other party has defined a namespace prefix `abc` with `http://hisdomain.com/test`. Then you insert your content in their XML file defining the same prefix `abc` with your domain `http://yourdomain.com/test`, getting something like this:

```
<abc:root xmlns:abc="http://hisdomain.com/test">
    <abc:width>100</abc:width>
    <abc:width xmlns:abc="http://yourdomain.com/test">200</abc:width>
</abc:root>
```

The scope of `http://hisdomain.com/test` is root and 100 width, while the scope of  `http://yourdomain.com/test` is 200 width. This is totally fine as long as both you and the other party are using query APIs that specify the full URI of the namespace. That way both you and they can find the correct element.

Reference

https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#scoping